# Servidor remoto/Servidor local em PHP

Tags: php, servidor, xampp, cliente-servidor, lado-do-servidor

Uma das opções para se criar um servidor web local é utilizar o XAMPP (PHP, SQL). Em um servidor web, tenho que instalar o XAMPP (ou qualquer suite semelhante) também ou ele é usado somente em servidores locais?

Comment: No servidor da hospedagem (compartilhada) já tem instalado uma versão do php e do mysql, fique atento para a versão de ambos para evitar problemas com funções obsoletas, configurações diferentes etc.

Comment: Depende de onde você for subir sua aplicação. As empresas, hoje, oferecem a opção de você gerenciar o seu próprio servidor (portanto, uma opção sua de instalar o XAMPP ou qualquer conjunto de aplicações pra transforma-lo num servidor web) ou algo já pré-configurado. Se você tem dúvidas, sugiro usar a opção de algum WebHost já configurado porque a configuração envolve questões técnicas de segurança e otimização de desempenho também.

Comment: Onde exatamente vai ficar hospedado?

Comment: Lembre-se que caso o seu ambiente de desenvolvimento seja igual ao de produção, irá facilitar muito as coisas na hora de debugar algum erro... as vezes uma pequena diferença de configuração pode demandar muito tempo até você descobrir o que é.

Comment: @Kenny Rafael ainda não escolhi o servidor que vou hospedar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os servidores de hospedagem oferecem o ambiente já configurado.

Não há necessidade em instalar Apache, PHP, MySQL, dentre outros.

Verifique com o seu provedor de hospedagem quais os recursos oferecidos. Pois cada empresa possui sua própria política de negócios.

Quando abre uma conta num provedor de hospedagem, receberá uma conta FTP. Pelo FTP poderá fazer o upload dos seus scripts PHP, as imagens, css, js, etc, para esse servidor online (hospedagem).

Answer (score 2):

XAMPP é uma aplicação que oferece um conjunto de recursos:

X - Significa que é multiplataforma.

A - Apache (Servidor que atua sob o protocolo HTTP)

M - MariaDB(Surgiu a partir do Mysql, Banco de Dados)

P - PHP

P - PERL(Originalmente PHP foi escrito a partir de um conjunto de scripts PERL)

Então se for montar um servidor você não precisa do XAMPP, você precisa de um servidor que atue sob o protocolo HTTP, uma base de dados, uma linguagem de script, um servidor de transferência de arquivos(FTP) e um servidor DNS...

Como dito pelo @DanielOmine, se for contratar uma hospedagem, elas já oferecem todo o conjunto (incluindo painel de administração) para várias plataformas... Mas se for montar um seu, precisará de um `IP fixo`, e configurar sua máquina conforme lhe for conveniente.

Por que não preciso de um servidor HTML, CSS, Javascript ?

Porque o navegador resolve isso para você...

Por que a maioria dos servidores no mundo são na plataforma Linux e não Windows?

Porque é grátissssssss, entre outros detalhes !!!!

Answer (score 2):

Uma **hospedagem compartilhada** já vem por padrão configurado para você apenas subir seu site sem se preocupar com configuração. A desvantagem é que ela funciona baseada em um ou mais servidores, que hospedam os arquivos de diversos usuários simultaneamente. Então um site com bastante tráfego não seria recomendado para esse tipo de hospedagem.

Num Servidor Virtual (VPS) ou Servidor Dedicado você tem um controle maior das aplicações. Alguns já vêm com algumas pré instalações. Porém você pode instalar o serviço que mais lhe agrada, como XAMPP, WAMPP.

Como respondido sua pergunta, numa hospedagem (maioria), você não tem como instalar o XAMPP ou parecido, apenas num VPS ou dedicado/cloud.